# What is the right way to typeset "define"?

Tags: math-mode, typography

One often uses `x:=t` which reads "`x` is defined to be `t`". What is the right way to typeset this in `LaTeX`?

Is it simply `\(x := t\)`?

I tried to google it around but couldn't find anything (probably because I didn't use the right keywords)

Comment: Duplicated for sure! Maybe it would be good to keep it closed, just to have another reference to the answer.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: I don't understand - I can see at the top a block with a link to the question which already exists. What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry. Dror/@egreg. For some reason I must have missed this link. I now see it. I looked for it yesterday but didn't see it. Anyway, my comment was made in good faith. I'll remove the comment.